# Facebook Canvas App Login URL doesn't look like other logins

Tags: oauth, facebook-login, facebook-oauth

So this is a canvas app, intended to run in the FB chrome.

I'm using the FB php SDK.

I'm creating my login url by:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array('scope'=>'email,publish_actions', 'redirect_uri'=>$fbCanvas));
```

then using this script to redirect:

```
print "<script> top.location.href='" . $loginUrl . "'</script>";
```

Instead of seeing a "regular" fb app auth dialog, such as:

[What I want to see](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30126/DesiredAuth.png)

I get a dialog like this one:

[What I see instead](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30126/GettingAuth.png)

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

If the new user clicks on the Okay button, they are logged into the app, redirected correctly and everything works ok, I just want it to look like / work like every other app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook is re-styling the Login dialog (again), see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/permissions-login-dialog/#login-dialog

As usual with Facebook, this rollout does not affect all users or all apps at the same time, but is gradually rolled out. So for a while users might see both versions of the login dialog, but eventually all apps will use the new one.

Comment: Thanks! The link is perfect. It does worry me a bit that my auth dialog would look different and that might cause confusion for my users... but I guess its something we have to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing nothing wrong.
I suspect Facebook has changed the way it displays the Authorization/Permission window depending on the data available for the Application. If your application lacks 'App Detail', 'Image' , 'Privacy Policy Link' etc. then you get the authorization window as What [major apps show](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30126/DesiredAuth.png) else you would get the window you are [getting right now](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30126/GettingAuth.png).
Earlier there was no distinction as such but since this month it might have changed as I earlier used to get the full fledged Authorization window but not now.

Comment: Thanks, since this is my first FB app, I was CERTAIN I was doing something wrong.